# How to integrate python script in Angular 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, angular, typescript, angular9

I have a python script that uses OpenCV to perform face detection. I want to integrate this script in my Angular app as I need to activate the webcam when the test starts and according to the value from python script the angular app needs to decide for routing to the next component.

Is it possible to do so?